# Is this the right way to do ipad media query?

Tags: ipad, css, media-queries

I have the following:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
.textular {
    font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

I got this from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ and I only need that above code.  It doesn't seem to work.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm a personal fan of separate style sheets. So, like `<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="ipad.css" />`

Comment: Which iPad? Generation 1,2,3 or all?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't  use (orientation: landscape) - you're much better off just defining more detailed media queries as this will take into account whether or not the tablet/iPad is in Portrait.

These are the media queries I use:

- **LANDSCAPE TABLET** (min-device-width : 901px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
- **PORTRAIT TABLET** (min-device-width : 721px) and (max-device-width : 900px)
- **MODERN SMARTPHONES** (min-device-width : 481px) and (max-device-width : 720px)
- **1ST GEN SMARTPHONES** (min-device-width : 361px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
- **LOW-RES SMARTPHONES** (max-device-width : 360px)

You also have to take into consideration whether or not the device is retina or non-retina. To show you an example, you would include (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) in your media query.

One thing you should check to see if it's the problem - in your original class 'textular', do you define font-size? I'm sure the problem is something very trivial.